# Is there float number in C# that represents an error while casting from string?

Tags: c#

I wrote this function:

```
public static float parseFloat(string number)
{
    float ishod = 0;

    try
    {
        float.TryParse(number.Replace(".", ","), out ishod);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ishod = -1;
        Console.WriteLine("parseFloat(): " + ex.Message);
    }

    return ishod;
}
```

because when entering float numbers like `4.5` in console application, it *doesn't see the dot* so it glues the two numbers. I get `45`.

Though it will work, it is dubious when you pass `0` or `-1` since you don't know if it produces error or a proper result.

I was wondering, does `float` type in C# has some *number constant* that *represents an error state*, so that I can return it and be sure something failed?
On the other hand what would be an error constant for integer in C#?

Or I should rethink my function and make it differently?

Comment: The Globalization Culture settings are wrong.  Instead of using Replace make the culture settings match the country/region where data is being entered.

Comment: probably `float.NaN` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, floating point values have *two* kind of separators: *decimal* and *thousand*, e.g.

```
 123,456,789.12
```

When parsing, thousand separators are *ignored* while decimal is turned into decimal point: `"123,456,789.12" -> 123456789.12`.
Please, note, that both separators are *culture specific*:

```
 "123.456.789,12" // Russian Culture, "ru-RU" - comma is a decimal separator         
 "123,456,789.12" // English Culture  "en-US" - dot is a decimal separator
```

In your case, you want to treat `'.'` as a *decimal separtor*, that's why let's parse it with *Invariant Culture* (your current culture treats `'.'` as a thousand separator and ignores it: `"1.2" -> 12`):

```
 using System.Globalization;

 ...  

 public static float parseFloat(string number) {
  // float.TryParse doesn't throw exceptions but returns true or false
  if (float.TryParse(number, 
                     NumberStyles.Any, 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                     out float result))
    return result;
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid floating point value.");

    // Not A Number
    return float.NaN;
  }
}
```

Possible usage:

```
  float value;

  do {
    Console.Write("Enter the value, please: ");
    // Keep asking user
    value = parseFloat(Console.ReadLine());
  }
  while (float.IsNaN(value)); // while the input provided is invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

The `TryParse` method will not throw an exception in case of failure, it will simply return false. This makes your method redundant - you can simply do:

```
if(float.TryParse(someStringValue, out float ishod))
{
    // success
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("failed to parse {0} to float.", someStringValue);
}
```

Comment: I used the same construct but it looks ugly and cluttered with this: float.TryParse(value.Replace(".", ","), out float ishod). I should try that Culture suff, but how do I set my application to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to return a float whatever the conversion makes then you can return NaN when you are sure:

```
public static float parseFloat(string number)
{
    float ishod = 0;

    try
    {
        float.TryParse(number.Replace(".", ","), out ishod);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ishod = float.NaN;
        Console.WriteLine("parseFloat(): " + ex.Message);
    }

    return ishod;
}
```

Comment: `float.TryParse` doesn't throw exception it returns `true` or `false`